# как можно реализовать чтение и вывод содержимого txt файла в JTextPane

Tags: java, input, jtextfield

Добрый день! Хотелось бы поинтересоваться как можно реализовать чтение и вывод содержимого `txt` файла в `JTextPane`.

я пробую так, но до конца дописать не хватает знаний. Буду рад помощи!

```
 private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        FileDialog      FD; // поиск файлов
    FD = new FileDialog(this, "Open file",FileDialog.LOAD);
    FD.show(); 
    // полный путь
    polnijput = FD.getDirectory()+FD.getFile();
    setTitle("Bloknot test" + " - " +polnijput);

    //чтениt данных из файлов
    FileInputStream FIS = null;//для чтения данных из файлов

    try
    {
      FIS = new FileInputStream(polnijput);

      buf = new byte[FIS.available()]; // массив байтов
      FIS.read(buf);//прочитанные данные
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
      System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }

    // массив buf теперь хранит прочитанныеданные
    // Выбираем всё содержимое тектсовой области
    jTex.selectAll();

jTex.cut(); // тут я вырезаю, так как метод удаления не знаю пока

    // Преобразуем массивв строку
    String szStr = new String(buf);

       StringTokenizer st;
    st = new StringTokenizer(szStr, " ");

    while(st.hasMoreElements())
    {
      szStr = new String((String)st.nextElement());// получаем очередной элемент и преобразуем его в строку

      // а вот тут его нужно записать. каким методом бы?




    }


    try
    {
     FIS.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
      System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }


    }   `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если кому интересно решение, то необходимо

```
class FileUtils {

    public String read(File file) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (!file.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("File not found!");
        }

        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsoluteFile()))) {
            String s;
            while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(s);
                sb.append("\n");
                //sb.append(new String(s, "windows-1251"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```